# Using an imported function save the output variables

Tags: python, spyder

I have two .py files, one with just functions and the other with code to run the functions.

When I use the following to run the function

```
from Code_function import some_function
some_function()
```

It runs the function but does not save the variable in the variable explorer (I am using spyder)

an example of a function from Code_function.py is

```
def some_function():
   global csv1
   csv1 = pd.read_csv('csv1.csv')
```

How would I make csv1 available in the variable explorer?

Comment: Can you try declaring the csv1 in first file. (with some default value like csv1 =  None)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to return your dataframe from a function, then call and assign it to your main file. This works for me

```
def some_function():
   global csv1
   csv1 = pd.read_csv('csv1.csv')

   return csv1
```

Main:

```
from Code_function import some_function
df = some_function()
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, **in Python, there's no need for output variables because a function can return multiple values** (strictly speaking, this is implemented as returning a tuple):

```
def fn():
    return 1,2
a,b = fn()
```

---

Now, regarding your question:

Though this is not specified in [7.12. The global statement — Python 3.7.3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=global#the-global-statement), a test shows that **`global` sets the name in the function's *lexical* scope** -- i.e. relative to where the function's code is.

So the `csv1` variable will end up in the `Code_function` module. If there's no name bound to that module object in your program, you'll have to access it as `sys.modules['<full name>']`:

```
>>> import Code_function
>>> Code_function.csv1
<...>
>>> sys.modules['Code_function'].csv1
<...>
```